# How to bind my javascript web app on IBM Bluemix with any Watson API service created by me in Manifest.yml?

Tags: node.js, yaml, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

How to bind my javascript web app on IBM Bluemix with any Watson API service created by me in Manifest.yml?

We followed the following tutorials to make tthis Watson Car Conversation - Simple app demo to work on my local computer and Bluemix hosting.
https://github.com/eGlobeBizCom/conversation-simple
This Q is also posted at the comments section of this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9M86BfL9KX0

*This demo app can work on my local computer;
*But deploying the above app to Bluemix, not successful.

## The problem: After type "cf push" on Gitbash, the results: Most steps are deployed, this step gives me the failed message:

## Failed. Could not find service conversation - free to bind to WatsonCarApp (This is the app name in the manifest.yml, I gave this app name)

Many searches on the web have no helpful info.  IBM Bluemix hosting and Watson API Service teams really need to improve tutorial and tech support.  Any suggestions will be appreciated.﻿

Comment: can you add your manifest.yml in your question? also, did you create the Watson service in Bluemix?

Comment: Why did you markdown this Q?  My Q on Bluemix hosting and Watson Services posted on several places received no answer and support from Bluemix team.

Comment: The manifest.yml file content is in the link of my above Q, here is the exact link and content: declared-services:
  conversation-free:
    label: conversation
    plan: free
applications:
- services:
  - conversation-free
  command: npm start
  path: .
  instances: 1
  memory: 512MB

Comment: I did not vote it down, i just asked for more details.

Comment: Apologize if you did not. Whoever did this is the uninformed person on this

Comment: Here is the link for this Watson demo app and yml file: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/manifest.yml

Comment: About "Watson service", I mentioned in my Q: I created this service, but have not see any Bluemix code example how to connect my web app with any Watson Service on bluemix. This has confused many people who tried Bluemix hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest.yml file expects a Watson Conversation service named `conversation-free`, so before you push your application you need to run the following command to create this service:

`$ cf create-service conversation free conversation-free`

after that you can run `cf push` to deploy your application.

These should fix the error you are seeing about not finding the `conversation-free` service.

If you created your Watson conversation service via UI, please use a manifest.yml file similar to below to deploy your application:

```
applications:
- name: WatsonCarApp
  services:
  - Conversation-4i
  command: npm start
  path: .
  instances: 1
  memory: 512MB
```

PS: manifest.yml assumes your application name is `WatsonCarApp` and your service name is `Conversation-4i`

Comment: Hi Alex,  Thanks for this info.  I finished the above step before I posted this Q and I tried several other ways to solve this problem already.  Now in my bluemix account, I have one Watson conversation service created called "Conversation-4i".  I tried to add this service name to yml file, but not working. where should this service name be added in ymal file?

Comment: I edited the answer with a sample file you can use to deploy your application.

Comment: Hi Alex,  The above seems to work. But this WatsonCarApp is still not working in Bluemix when I visited the web address. The new problem seems to be the port number based on the error messages:

Comment: This Watson car-simple app demo is configured to work on local computer at this port:3000. The error message said that the port number in this app is hard-coded.   I went over the following bluemix tutorial to change the port number in this app, but this tutorial doe not provide the details on the code change for Bluemix web server. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-fundamentals-create-and-deploy-a-node-app-to-the-cloud/#step6;  Any suggestions on this?

Comment: If you are using the code in the github link you added in your question the application should work fine. I tried and I can deploy and run it. This file https://github.com/eGlobeBizCom/conversation-simple/blob/master/server.js has the code you need to use to get the right port number.

Comment: I did not change anything in the above server.js file from Github.  I did " cf push" again. I did not get error message on port number  this times. Something strange happened with Bluemix server.  Now the WatsonCarApp is running inside my account on Bluemix. But, some else went wrong and make this app not working properly.  More is below.

Comment: Now the Watson car app is running inside our account at this link: http://watsoncarapp.mybluemix.net.  This page says: "The app has not been configured with a WORKSPACE_ID environment variable. Please refer to the README documentation on how to set this variable. 
Once a workspace has been defined the intents may be imported from here in order to get a working application."  The situation is caused by this: The .env file in this app on my computer exists. After several "cf push", I found that this .env file cannot be pushed into Bluemix server, but this .env.example file is pushed to Bluemix.

Comment: In Bluemix server, how can we upload one single file into this app? Thanks !

Comment: You cannot push a single file to Bluemix, but I noticed that your .cfignore file lists .env, hence the reason you cannot push your .env file. Please update the .cfignore and remove the .env line so .env can be pushed to the application. The .cfignore file works similar .gitignore and does push the directories/files listed there to Bluemix app.

Comment: after updating .cfignore you have to run `cf push` again

Comment: I tried to follow the following Watson Personality App to push the app to my bluemix account.  https://github.com/eGlobeBizCom/personality-insights-nodejs.  After " cf push", all the files are uploaded. I clicked the great " Restart" button, but the app cannot run. On the Bluemix page, it says "Your app is not running",     here is the app link: friendfit.mybluemix.net  .   Any suggestions will be great !

Comment: Here is the error message for the above problem:
"an instance of the app crashed: failed to accept connections within health check timeout
exit status: 255, CRASHED"

Comment: I'd recommend you read the debugging section for Bluemix here https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/debug/index.html#debugging to familiarize yourself on how to look at the logs and other tips to further investigate your problem. If that does not help, please ask a new question so it can have greater visibility and have other users to help as well. Adding a comment here will only alert myself.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the reply. I found out the causes of the above error: My apps used the same Watson API Service created by me. Now i learned this: Each app needs to link to its own Watson API Service on Bluemix.  This point should be strongly pointed out to new Bluemix hosting user.

Answer (score 0):

Now the above demo app works in my account in Bluemix. The people who are new to Bluemix or Watson app, need to read the above comments carefully in order to get the app run on Bluemix. Thanks for the timely replies from Alex.

Hope someone who understands Watson conversation API can reply my following Q related to this: 
[IBM Watson Car-Dashboard demo gave wrong replies to some of my Q in my copy of this demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512593/ibm-watson-car-dashboard-demo-gave-wrong-replies-to-some-of-my-q-in-my-copy-of-t)